# NodeJS and C# app EBUSY error

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, npm

I am currently developing an nodeJS app. I use a simple C# program to create a text file. That file is like a token which helps me to continue the execution of nodeJS app.I have the following javascript code:

```
function take_tool() {
    while(take_tool_flag == false) {
        if(fs.existsSync('D:/flag.txt')) {
            fs.writeFileSync('D:/input_robot.txt', '-1');
            console.log('Robot is taking the tool!');
            fs.unlinkSync('D:/flag.txt');
            take_tool_flag = true;
        }
    }
}

function draw_table() {
    while(draw_table_flag == false && take_tool_flag == true) {
        if(fs.existsSync('D:/flag.txt')) {
            fs.writeFileSync('D:/input_robot.txt', '-3');
            console.log('Robot is drawing the table game!');
            fs.unlinkSync('D:/flag.txt');
            draw_table_flag = true;
        }
    }
}


function game() {

    console.log("Game has started!");

    fs.writeFileSync('D:/input_robot.txt', '-99');

    take_tool();

    draw_table();
}

game();
```

And this is the code for C# program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("File created!");
                File.Create(@"D:\flag.txt", 1024);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run the nodeJS app with "node filename.js" and then it wait for flag.txt to be created. But when i run C# program i get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas? Node version: 6.9.2.

Comment: Instead of `x == false` it's usually better to do `!x` as that's more concise. Also instead of sharing data over files, which is super messy, why not a TCP connection? Websocket makes this pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you for feedback! The file flag.txt is created when a resource,in my case,a robot is available. Then trough my nodejs app i send back commands to robot using input_robot.txt file. I don't have another alternatives.

Comment: The alternative is a socket. Shared files are a world of hurt, especially when you're deleting them and they're still being held open and such. Look at Websocket. C# has good support as well. The alternative is to spin and retry aggressively on errors which could be really CPU intensive.

Comment: I found a temporary solution. System.IO.File.Create(@"D:\flag.txt", 1024).Close();. But i will take a look at Websocket. I am sure that there are many more elegant solutions.

Comment: What you're describing here seems to be a primitive form of inter-process communication (IPC). There's many ways to do it, some better than others. A wrapper like [Socket.io](http://socket.io) makes it pretty easy to set this up, no server required per-se.

Comment: I will try. Thank you everyone for advice me.